# Form Input blank on refresh

Tags: wordpress, forms, input

I have a simple form field...

```
<input class="text-input" name="first_name" type="text" id="first-name" value="<?php the_author_meta( 'first_name', $current_user->ID ); ?>" />
```

It pulls the value correctly from the Wordpress database and displays.  If I then delete what is in the input box so it is blank and then press refresh, when the page refreshes the box is still blank.

Am I missing something obvious?  Should it not pull the value in again and display it?

Comment: It should actually. But sometimes, refresh button will only bring the data from cache.. Can you show a bit more code what you are doing in the page..?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/umZteebB

Comment: Try Ctrl+R to refresh and let me know whether it results into the same or not...

Comment: Ctrl+R, F5 and clicking the reload button all give the same results.  If I actually select the URL from the address bar and hit enter then the values come back

Answer (score 0):

If you set the attribute `autocomplete=off`, the content will never be stored. And each time page gets refresh, it will load the content accordingly.

Alternatively, there's are lots of ways to accomplish this with javascript, depending on exactly what you want to accomplish, whether it be clearing the whole form or resetting the single field. But that should be before the php load your data into the fields..

Let me know whether this worked for you or not.

Hope it helps.